# How do I Unlock the "???" Character?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac

I just found out (in the [wiki](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/%3F%3F%3F)) that there's a character called ??? in *Binding of Isaac*. However, the page doesn't say how to unlock him. I also haven't had immediate luck on google (try googling "???" =/), so here I am.

How do I unlock the "???" character?

Comment: Sheesh as if this game wasn't hard enough to beat just a single time...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually in the [wiki](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Unlockables):

> ??? | Character | Defeat the boss in The Womb 2 for the tenth time.

Comment: Hi Wieland, welcome to gaming.SE. While that link indeed contains the information asked for, it is highly appreciated to quote relevant information, both to counter link rot and to provide useful information directly here

Comment: That information is actually different from the other answers. "The Womb 2" only unlocks after having beaten the game once (or twice?). So saying "Beat the game 10 times" is different to "Beat The Womb 2 10 times". Can anyone verify which one is correct?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's "Beat the boss in The Womb 2 ten times" because the game is not considering beating Mom in The Depths 2 a playthrough - the "Mom Kills" in the stats are only increased when killing Moms heart. Furthermore the steam achievements and unlockables in-game which depend on the number of game completions are also unlocked depending on your number of "Mom Kills".

Answer (score 7):

You have to beat the game ten times to unlock him. You don't have to do it with any particular character, you just need to do it ten times.

Comment: Does he show up in the characters list before unlocking him?

Comment: Nope, unlike the other characters he doesn't show up in the character list until you unlock him.

Comment: Well... Back to the grind, I suppose.

Answer (score 6):

You must defeat "[It Lives](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/It_Lives)" which replaces Mom's Heart on your 10th playthrough.

Comment: Can't it happen that after failing at "It Lives", the tenth time beating the game is against mom's heart again?

Comment: @TobiasKienzler, I've only beaten "It Lives" once, but I thought that every time after that it replaced Mom's Heart?  I can't find any sources that back this up though, so you might be right.

Comment: I also can't remember for sure whether I ever encountered mom's heart again...

Comment: @TobiasKienzler "It Lives" will replace Mom's heart for every playthrough once it's enabled after your 9th kill, regardless of defeating it or not.

Comment: @TheQ ok, in that case, agent86's answer is equivalent to beating the game 10 times.