# Why am I peeing?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac

In Binding of Isaac, I notice that I sometimes leave a little pee puddle upon entering a room. What's causing Isaac to urinate? Is it random or based on an item or effect I have at the moment?

[image]

Comment: ...  this is one question that probably is fine *without* a picture.

Comment: @agent86 but it's so weird/funny/gross. A picture would make this question even better :)

Comment: We are now the #2 search result for "Binding of Isaac Peeing". Clearly we need a picture to be the #1 resource on peeing.

Comment: @BenBrocka I keep trying to get a picture but I keep dying before I can leave a room with half a heart so that it will happen. So frustrating!

Comment: Why in the world would anyone downvote this?

Comment: @Tristan I know :( It made me so sad

Comment: Bahahahaha another great title to show up on my feed!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's a warning to remind you that your health is critical, i.e. that you only have half a Heart left.

[image: screenshot]

As long as you're at half a regular Heart (regardless of how many Soul/Faith Hearts you have), you will soil yourself in terror each time you enter a room.

(If you're playing as [???](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/45774/how-do-i-unlock-the-character), this will happen when your Faith is critical instead, because he has no regular health.)

Comment: I was about to ask about ???

Comment: @BenBrocka I *think* you used to pee all the time when using him, but anyway it's not the case now, for obvious reasons. Still not sure what happens if you lose all your regular hearts when playing someone else. That's generally not a thing that happens.

Comment: Ohh yeah, if you have 3 soul hearts you can live with 0 hearts. I'd assume you pee then as well.

Comment: @BenBrocka How can you still have soul hearts but not have regular hearts left? The soul hearts are used up before the regular hearts are hurt...

Comment: @spugsley If you buy items from Satan, you can pay with heart slots. If you can't pay, you die, but presumably if you have Faith left over, you might be able to go on. I have no idea, because getting rid of all your hearts on purpose is a dumb move and I've never attempted it.

Comment: @spugsley wiki said so, though I can't find where it says it now. I think it was in regards to the Whore of Babylon strategy or the Devil Room.